# Creating a Histogram from Multiple Choice Grid Data in Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a data from Google Forms that came from a multiple choice grid. I need to recreate the histogram that was created in the Google Forms in Google Data Studio.

[image: Goal]

Here is the data. How can I recreate it in Google Data Studio? It has turned out to be surprisingly challenging.

[Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G0FdCp-O_4fMzyX0oA6S0OlSwmvbjpnFKtYHv6Q2DUc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to unpivot the columns B, C, D (which are your questions) . I did it Power Query using Excel (Office 365) because unpivoting columns in Google Sheets is a huge pain, and not done by default. The new expanded column will help you get the desired histogram.